# Small tiles that get bigger when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a webpage with several small tiles that enlarge when clicked (And show more/different content, but that's not a part of this question).

This is what I have now: http://puu.sh/nX929.png
When I click on the first tile, it looks exactly like I want it to: http://puu.sh/nX9l9.png
But when I click the second tile it looks like this: http://puu.sh/nX95G.png (gap on the left)
That's not what I want, I want to other (small) tiles to float around it. To fill the empty space.
The source code (+ live example) can be found here (but I wouldn't mind doing it in a completely different way): https://www.crescendosassenheim.nl/Hugo/Training/

I don't even know what to Google, because I have absolutely no idea what kind of technique I can use to achieve what I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html Take a look at this I am sure this will help you, what you want is even displayed at the bottom of the page i am linking.
Download masonry in your computer link to it and follow the little guide in their website.

Comment: This is beautiful, I didn't even know "Masonry" existed :)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want! Thank you very much.